# Unhealthy PI behavior

Tags: postdocs, harassment

What is your opinion on a situation where a PI informs a postdoc that their presence is attributed to the PI's efforts and salary funding, thereby implying certain behavioral expectations? Do you believe it's acceptable for the PI to subsequently ignore the postdoc, cease communication, or withhold opportunities related to the postdoc's work, especially after the postdoc raises concerns about an imbalance between administrative duties and research responsibilities? What would you recommend the post-doc to do in this situation?

Comment: I think it would be better to directly state one problem here as a question, rather than as an oblique solicitation of opinion like "yeah that sucks!". For example, the first sentence doesn't seem to have any relationship at all to ceasing communication with a trainee which doesn't have any relationship to an imbalance between administrative and research responsibilities. What's the actual question you have where answers to the question would help your situation?

Comment: In that case, it would be sufficient to address the second part of the question:Do you believe it's acceptable for the PI to subsequently ignore the postdoc, cease communication, or withhold opportunities related to the postdoc's work, especially after the postdoc raises concerns about an imbalance between administrative duties and research responsibilities? What would you recommend the post-doc to do in this situation?

Comment: What does your university's ombudsperson/HR (or equivalent confidential resource) think?

Comment: No, it's not acceptable for any supervisor to cease all communication with one of their employees or trainees; do you need to go further with that? Does that answer help you achieve anything to change the situation? I'm guessing not. I don't know what the post doc has already done (or what actual behaviors they're describing; what does it mean to ignore or cease communication e.g. how much time has elapsed? what's the evidence this is connected to a complaint and not, say, the professor's health?), so I don't know how to advise them.

Comment: The HR department appears to be highly inefficient in this situation. When I initially approached the PI regarding my need to focus on research and allocate time for drafting a publication, they redirected me to the department chair. Subsequently, I've been engaged in meetings with both the chair and the PI, who present themselves as a united front.

Comment: When I established a structured work plan for the ethnography, outlining the time required for each task, I was informed that there would be no additional time allocated for drafting publications or conducting literature reviews. They insisted that I had only four months to conduct approximately 90 semi-structured interviews lasting about an hour each, in addition to field observations. Furthermore, I was asked to manage various other tasks, such as writing reports, reviewing reports, organizing workshops, and facilitating knowledge transfer between work packages, all concurrently.

Comment: I informed them that I had already been involved in organizing workshops, drafting three reports, and reviewing others. I emphasized my urgent need for dedicated time to focus on my research and allocate time for drafting articles. However, following this discussion, the PI began to exhibit troubling behavior. They stopped communicating with me, ceased answering my questions, and started ignoring me during meetings. Whenever I approached the PI with inquiries or requests, they either abruptly left or requested that I leave, claiming that I was intruding on their time.

Comment: That’s not normal behaviour. Make sure to read your contract and see what reasons they could invoke to end it earlier than planned. Start looking for other positions if you haven’t already. That being said, it is true that unless you have your own funding, your PI is your boss and you should do what they ask, within reason.

Comment: I am employed in a country with stringent termination regulations based on an employee's circumstances. Additionally, the law mandates that postdoctoral researchers must allocate their contractual time to activities aimed at facilitating their progression to an associate professorship. Furthermore, there exists a Career Development Plan that places a strong emphasis on publications, grant applications, and teaching opportunities, which must be adhered to and respected. Yet, they have not even signed under my Career Development Plan.

Comment: Don't we need to know what precipitated these statements and actions before we can say whether it's a reasonable approach or not??  Yo described the *end* of a situation, and asked us for opinions.  We need to know the beginning and middle, too.

Comment: Well, I told it. I spent months working on non-research related admin tasks. When I finally raised the issue of needing dedicated time for research and publication, the PI brought the department chair into the conversation, and our communication came to a halt. We've had meetings with the chair. The PI expects me to undertake a significant amount of non-research work while I am keen to concentrate on research. In the meantime, the PI stopped talking to me at all etc. -above-mentioned behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing the full situation, it reads to me like this:

Your postdoc position was likely created to help run certain tasks on a project or body of projects. As you noted the PI pointed out that the postdoc position exists due to their efforts/funding, etc... That is correct. Postdoc positions emerge out of some funding scheme, usually federal or private for which the PI applied and was rewarded, or via some internal University-level scheme, which again is typically competitive and requires the PI to put in some effort to justify need, and usually some downstream ROI that makes it worthwhile.

It seems to me you were expecting a role which had more leeway for professional development, CV building, etc (which is the norm but not the rule for postdoc positions). Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be the case for you, which is completely disappointing, and you have my sympathies.

Your PI obviously has/had expectations that you are not meeting, and vice-versa. Trying to diagnose the way they are dealing with this, referring to it as troubling, and so forth, is not really productive. Nor is bringing HR into the issue. Sure, it is not professional behavior, but you don't know the underlying issues of your PI which have led them to this form of expression.

The truth is not all postdocs work out, and not all professional and interpersonal relationships work out either. My suggestion is wrap up what you are doing and start applying for positions which clearly meet your desires for personal and professional growth.

What you may find down the line is that all of these administrative tasks will help you tremendously in your professional career. As faculty, I do about as much admin as I do writing papers or thinking about science (sad, I know). Unfortunately while I was trained very well to do science, I went into my independent career with no admin experience which made me less efficient in my early years. So take the positives and move on.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've already initiated a search for another position. I've come to realize that the definition of "research" here, which involves fieldwork, data collection, and analysis, differs significantly from my own standards. Furthermore, my mentor has conveyed to me that they are merely expecting mediocrity, whereas I have higher aspirations for my work.

Comment: I feel that I am not fully realizing my potential in my current position, and I'm growing increasingly skeptical about the potential for publications. Despite promises of co-authorship and authorship, it appears that other individuals within the project are and will continue to be the primary co-authors with the PI.

Comment: @Klmnr I don't know why you'd expect to take authorship away from people already working on a project.

Comment: I'm not seeking to displace anyone from authorship. I wholeheartedly support the Vancouver recommendations, and I never claim authorship for anything I haven't personally written. What I'm referring to is the -promised- potential to be actively engaged in co-writing for future publications, which was a topic we had previously discussed within the work package. It appears that there are now limited prospects for such involvement, as our standards and expectations diverge and I am effectively excluded from opportunities that would contribute to my career development in this regard.

Comment: @Klmnr Then why even mention "other individuals within the project are and will continue to be the primary co-authors"? Of course they will, they're working on the project. If you have a quarrel that you *won't* have anything to author, then focus on that, not the other people.

Comment: I am concerned about the prospect of not having substantial research outcomes to author, primarily due to the lack of dedicated time for rigorous research. The PI does not give me time for that. Additionally, I am uncertain about being invited to collaborate as a co-author with others. It is in the humanities and social sciences field. It's important to note that our field adheres to distinct conventions of publication and research practices.

Comment: "I've come to realize that the definition of "research" here, which involves fieldwork, data collection, and analysis, differs significantly from my own standards." I am really curious to here what your definition of research would then be.

Comment: My understanding of research of course encompasses literature review, data collection and data analysis, I mean how they define it and what they mean by those terms differ from the best practices I adhere to. For instance, I am informed that ethnographical field observation for them simply means conducting interviews on site and not online or on phone. That is unacceptable and simply wrong in my opinion.

Comment: @Klmnr I'm having a hard time reading your comment as anything but "They think you need to go out in the field for research but I want to do it all from home" which makes it sound like you're not willing to put in the work rather than not being granted the opportunity.

Answer (score 2):

Having read all the comments on this question and its answers, the core disconnect that strikes me is that you expect to focus on your research but feel that you are not given the time for it -- while at the same time, there is no acknowledgment that the institution you're at pays your salary and will have expectations in turn.

It is of course entirely possible (perhaps likely) that the university's expectations of your time are unrealistic and not in line with what they promised you up front. But at the same time, seeing no acknowledgment on your side that *some* work for the university other than the research you want to do is not unreasonable, you come over as wanting to have your cake and eat it too. This is not typically how this works, and any compromise one would hope for you to find with your employer will have to start at a mutual acknowledgment that the other side has a point *at least in principle*.

Comment: I am currently involved in two projects (that pay my salary), and my job description outlines the following responsibilities: a) data collection and analysis, b) authoring and co-authoring scientific articles, and c) workshop organization. Throughout the interview process and initial interactions, it was emphasized that my primary responsibility would be fieldwork (research) for one of the projects. I also explicitly stated that I had primarily undertaken administrative tasks for approximately five months.

Comment: However, I must clarify that I was not informed about the specific breakdown of research versus administrative work (percentage-wise) during the job interviews. I now request this information from the university. In your view, what would be a suitable distribution between administrative and research tasks for a postdoc, taking into account the job description provided? It's important to emphasize that in my country, the law defines a postdoctoral position as a preparation for associate professorship, focusing on three key areas: teaching, grant writing, and publications.

Comment: I think that very much depends on the position, where the money comes from, etc. But I think it is not unreasonable to expect that you spend 50% or more of your time on work that is not for you (e.g., teaching and administration).